Harmonize Label Annotation when merging multiple datasets (ML)
I want to build a ML model for fake news detection. There are multiple datasets out there that use different labeling schemes. For example, the LIAR dataset allows for 6-ways classsification (true, false, half-true, mostly-true, etc.), whereas the FakeNewsNet dataset provides only 2 labels (real/fake).
Even though I know that there are approaches that do not involve "merging" the datasets (e.g. transfer learning, multi-task learning), my goal is to find a way to combine two (or more) datasets into one so that eventually, a single model can be trained on all data.
I am therefore looking for a way to harmonize the label schemes of multiple datasets (ds).
Let's say, ds A has 3 labels (true/false and hate-speech) and ds B has 4 labels (true/half-true/false and satire). In A and B, 'satire' and 'hate-speech' don't exclude other labels for an instance. The task is to create a ds C consisting of the unity of all instances in A and B. Each instance of C has a label that encodes class membership for true/half-true/false/satire/hate-speech.

match the different granularities of fake-news in A and B. That means, allowing instances of A to be half-true instead of true/false.

Extend the label scheme of A (and B) by a label that is not necessarily linked to other labels in A (and B). That is, allowing instances of A (B) to be not only true/false/half-true but also satire (hate-speech) at the same time.


I'm looking for ways to combine A and B into one ds. References to scientific papers are welcome!
Thanks :)
Ideas I have gathered so far:
-Guide feature method [Jiang 2019]: Train model B on ds B. Then use model B to classify A (and thereby labeling it).
-Meta Learning for Soft Labels [Vyas 2020]: Labels become a trainable real-value parameter (this could help overcoming the "different granularities" problem.
